# Jquery draggable and saving into database

Tags: html, jquery

Today I started learning jquery ui. I created an example frontend where I have 7 days a week. I ran into a problem and I have question. There is any option to drag div (as frontend) and drop it into other div? I mean now I can drag my "gray rectangle" into other day, but im not sure that save in the HTML code.
My point is that if I change postion of my gray rectangle (for example to "day 2") and want to save in the database what day it is, will it save main setting (day 1) or after moving (day 2)?

```
 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#here", snap: ".day" });
  } );
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container pt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h1>November 2021</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center bg-dark text-white">
            <h5 class="col-sm">Monday</h5>
            <h5 class="col-sm">Tuesday</h5>
            <h5 class="col-sm">Wednesday</h5>
            <h5 class="col-sm">Thursday</h5>
            <h5 class="col-sm">Friday</h5>
            <h5 class="col-sm">Saturday</h5>
            <h5 class="col-sm">Sunday</h5>  
        </div>
        <div class="row border-bottom " id="here">
           <div class="col-sm border p-2 day ">
              <div class="col-12"><span >1</span></div>
               <div class="col-12 rounded bg-secondary small draggable" >a</div>
           </div>
            <div class="col-sm border p-2 day" style="height: 100px;">
               <div class="col-12"><span >2</span></div>
               <div class="row align-items-center h-100">        
               </div>
           </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gknyo9pm/